# Element authentication does not contain element credentials

Tags: asp.net

Now I read a book "ASP.NET MVC5" by Freeman and I try to create authentification window. But I've changed file Web.config like in the book and have error.

```
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
      <credentials passwordFormat="Clear"> <!-- Error -->
        <user name="admin" password="secret" />
      </credentials>
    </authentication>
  </system.web>
```

*Error: **authentication** does not contain element **credentials**.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your credentials element should be within your forms element. Something like:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880">
      <credentials passwordFormat="Clear"> <!-- Error -->
        <user name="admin" password="secret" />
      </credentials>
  </forms>
</authentication>als>
```